# converting a datetime in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime-format

I have the following datetime format (Mai 2, 2018 6:35:52 AM) which I want to convert to %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f format, such as: 2017-05-13 21:11:01.436757

I have tried every way I can think of but get errors

```
customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE2'] = customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE'].str.replace(',','')
print(customer_file_path[['RECEIVED_DATE2']].head(10))
customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE2'] = pd.to_datetime(customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE2'], format='%b %e %Y %-I:%M:%S %p', errors='coerce')
print(customer_file_path[['RECEIVED_DATE2']].head(10))

customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE3'] = pd.to_datetime(customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE2']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')#, errors='coerce')
customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE2'] = pd.to_datetime(customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE2'], format='%b %e %Y %-I:%M:%S %p').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')#, errors='coerce')

customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE3'] = pd.to_datetime(customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE2'], format='%b %e %Y %-I:%M:%S %p').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')#, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: i get ValueError: Unknown string format for the first received_date3 and ValueError: 'e' is a bad directive in format '%b %e %Y %-I:%M:%S %p' for the second received_date3

Comment: i set the locale to deu_deu whic hsolves the problem with "Mai" but now getting ValueError: unconverted data remains: am